# Is there any way to send email to users with attachment using SharePoint/office 365?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, smtp, office365, smtpclient

I have created a PowerShell script to send email with attachment getting the below error. Is there another way or how to resolve the below issue ?

**Error:**

Exception: Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Error in processing. The server response was: 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail [BM1PR0101CA0039.INDPRD01.
PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"

**PowerShell Script:**

```
function send-emailwithattachment( [string] $subject, [string] $body, [string] $FilesPath  )
{
    $smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
    $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $to= "raj@qwert.com"
    $cc= "Raman@qwert.com", "rama@qwert.com"

    $emailSmtpUser="nanda@qwert.com"
    $emailSmtpPass="ZXCCXZ@ASD"

    #Change port number for SSL to 587
    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 

    #Uncomment Next line for SSL  
    #$smtp.EnableSsl = $true

    #From Address
    $msg.From = "nanda@qwert.com"
    #To Address, Copy the below line for multiple recipients
    $msg.To.Add($to)
    $msg.Cc.Add($cc)

    #Message Subject
    $msg.Subject = $subject
    $msg.Body = $body

    #$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList $FilesPath
    $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList D:\ListData.csv
    $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)

    $smtp.EnableSsl = $False
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass,"qwert.com" );
   
    $smtp.Send($msg)
    $msg.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage)? You're setting `$smtp.EnableSsl = $False`. Try that with `$smtp.EnableSsl = $true`

Comment: Just found an example. Will try to chg it to True and check.